# How to access magento Session in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, session, magento, integration

I have read many questions similar to this,

but found no answer

i have to display customer name and cart items in wordpress blog

I have installed Mage Enabler .but always it is showing Invalid Url.
what can be valid url for local pc?

so i also have done like,

```
    require_once ("../app/Mage.php");
umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array('name' => 'frontend'));
    $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

    if($session->isLoggedIn())
      {echo "YES";}
    else {echo "NO";}
```

I always get "NO" .. :(

Can anyone please help me how to access magento session in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
```

Try:

```
$session=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name'=>'frontend') );
```

Good luck